# Как заблокировать изменение приложение под черную тему телефона?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

создаю приложение на Xamarin Forms и не могу заблокировать изменение темы приложения, если у человека на телефоне стоит темная тема. Пробовал решить данную проблему с помощью следующей строчки(писал ей на главной странице приложения - MainPage):

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Light;
```

Но в приложении после её написания, ничего не изменилось.